# remove decimal seperator and decimals from a string (price) value

Tags: php

How would I convert number strings 10,000 to 10

```
$priceMin = 10,000;
(int)str_replace(',', '', $priceMin);
```

I've tried this but that outputs 10000

Comment: `echo (int) '10,000';` gives me 10.

Comment: `$ten = intval("10,000");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($priceMin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `,` with `.` using [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) and [typecast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to a [`float`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

```
$priceMin = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $priceMin);
```

**Example**:

```
<?php

$numbers = array('10,000', '20,000', '30,000', '12,345');

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $number = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $number);

    var_dump($number);
}
```

**Output:**

```
float(10)
float(20)
float(30)
float(12.345)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/uCoxYMyH)

Comment: Good answer but I guess he just wants an integer value. Cast the string to integer will stop at the `,`. KISS and don't use str_replace (If I understand the owner's achievement otherwise ignore this).